# How to price barrier options under Black-Scholes?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, barrier

I am looking for a rigorous proof for the closed form of the price of a barrier option (up-in/up-out) under Black-Scholes model, that is a step by step solution of the solution of the heat equation where the initial condition is given by the barrier price.

Comment: I believe [Steven Shreve, Stochastic calculus for finance II](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X), have a section about barrier options (Ch. 7). Maybe that will be of help.

Comment: This [PDF paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/howison/barriers.pdf) from Oxford university is pretty decent at explaining Barrier pricing within the BS framework (they take the PDE approach, so if you like differential equations, you might like the paper).